# Trying to make an exit statement with this C code

Tags: c, exit

Hey trying to make an exit statement that is the user enters a value less than one it prints an error message and exits the program.  I have a variable called InputCount.  I was thinking of doing an if else or something but I already have a do/while and its messing up my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define KILOMETERS_PER_MILE 1.609 // declaration of a symbolic constant

int main() {
    // definition of variables we use in this program
    double kilometers; // variable to store kilometers
    double miles; // variable to store miles
    do {
        // ask the user for input and store it in variable miles
        printf("Please enter the distance in miles: \n ");
        int inputCount = scanf("%lf", &miles);
        if (inputCount != 1) {
            return 2;
        }
    
//printf("ERROR: invalid input. Program has stopped.");

        // calculate the equivalent value of kilometers 
        kilometers = miles * KILOMETERS_PER_MILE;
        printf("That is equal to %.2f kilometers.\n", kilometers);
    } while (miles != 0);
puts("ERROR: invalid input. Program has stopped.");
    printf("Thank you for calculating with us today. \n");
  
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you want to *conditionally* exit the program, then a *conditional* statement is required to control that.  An `if` seems the most likely candidate in this case.  There's no particular reason why that should conflict with a `do` / `while` loop (or any other kind of loop).

Comment: Ok I tried that, the error I am now facing is the program ends with a 0 but it doesn't print my error message.

Comment: `if (!(inputCount == 1))` is more traditionally written `if (inputCount != 1)`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger They edited the question to show it, refresh.

Comment: Ah I just moved the print statement

Comment: When I run your program I get the error message and exit code 2.

Comment: Weird I just updated the code on the page again (sorry new to the site).  It works as it is intended to do.  

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```c
if (miles <= 1.0) {
  printf("Wrong input '%d'\n",inputCount);
  exit(1);    // instead of breaking the loop, it aborts the program.
}
```

Don't forget
`#include <stdlib.h>`

##### Demo of the full code

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define KILOMETERS_PER_MILE 1.609 // declaration of a symbolic constant

int main() {
    // definition of variables we use in this program
    double kilometers; // variable to store kilometers
    double miles; // variable to store miles
    do {
        // ask the user for input and store it in variable miles
        printf("Please enter the distance in miles: \n ");
        scanf("%lf", &miles);
        if (miles <= 1.0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Wrong input : %f\n", miles);
            exit(1);
        }
        // calculate the equivalent value of kilometers 
        kilometers = miles * KILOMETERS_PER_MILE;
        printf("That is equal to %.2f kilometers.\n", kilometers);
    } while (miles != 0);
    printf("Thank you for calculating with us today. \n");
    return 0;
}
```

- Compile and run:

  ```
    gcc -Wall demo.c -o demo.out
    ./demo.out
  ```
- Output:

  ```
  Please enter the distance in miles: 
   1.5
  That is equal to 2.41 kilometers.
  Please enter the distance in miles: 
   0.5
  Wrong input : 0.500000
  ```